# Symfony DependencyInjection - how to get all services of certain type?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

Using CompilerPass, I need to add setter to all services that inherit specific abstract class. **They're already tagged, but ONLY SOME OF THEM use abstract class.**

Something like that:

```
$abstractServices = $containerBuilder->findServicesByType('MyAbstractClass');

$abstractServices->addMethodCall(
    'setHelperService',
    [new Reference('@service_to_be_set')
);
```

What would you suggest?

Comment: Did you try to use a abstract service? in this case you could define the set only in your parent service in all the child services would inherit this

Comment: Could you link me to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check if the service class is subclass of the specified abstract class.

```
foreach ($container->getDefinitions() as $definition) {
    if (is_subclass_of($definition->getClass(), 'YourAbstractClass')) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use this in a practice?

Comment: No. Take a look at abstract services.

Comment: Could you share some link? Google gave some various random sources.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parentservices.html

Comment: This adds complexity for the end user not to forget to add parent to the config. The goal is to make it as simple as possible to register new service.  I'll go with your suggested solution. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Based on Thomas's answer

```
$taggedServices = $container->findTaggedServiceIds('your_tag');

foreach ($taggedServices as $id => $tags) {
    $service = $container->findDefinition($id); 
    if (!is_callable($service, 'yourMethodName') {
        continue;
        // or raise exception if you need
    }
    $service->addMethodCall(...); //whatever
}
```

Another way would be

```
$taggedServices = $container->findTaggedServiceIds('your_tag');

foreach ($taggedServices as $id => $tags) {
    $service = $container->findDefinition($id); 
    if (!$service instance YourInterface) {
        continue;
        // or raise exception if you need
    }
    $service->addMethodCall(...); //whatever
}
```

Of course event that is based on tags and works only with instances or abstract classes (if method you're searching for is abstract in the latter case)

Comment: This is bit workaround, but seems the best so far. Thank you. Could you think of something else not using the tag?

Comment: @TomášVotruba if Tomasz had not answered, I would have answer the same, so no, i think is the best way :)

Comment: I wouldn't really consider it a workaround, the answer seems like a perfectly legitimate way to do what you're doing.